# Click on infoBox does not execute javascript mapped to "click" function

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, infowindow

I use the following code on my google map to include infoBox.

```
          var myOptions = {
             content: '<div>' + message + '</div>'
            ,disableAutoPan: false
            ,maxWidth: 0
            ,pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(-80, 0)
            ,zIndex: null
            ,boxStyle: {
              background: "#add8e6"
              ,opacity: 0.9
              ,width: "160px"
             }
            ,closeBoxMargin: "2px 2px 2px 2px"
            ,closeBoxURL: "http://www.google.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/close.gif"
            ,infoBoxClearance: new google.maps.Size(1, 1)
            ,isHidden: false
            ,pane: "floatPane"
            ,enableEventPropagation: false
          };

          var ib = new InfoBox(myOptions);
          ib.open(map, mark);
          infowindow_opened = ib;
```

That works fine (the infoBox appears).

The message I display in the box is the following one:

```
'<a class="test">click test</a>';
```

It's a "a" tag without any href information as the logic of clicking on this item is handled in javascript:

$('a.test').click(function(){ alert("clicked')});

When I click on the link "click test" within the infoBox, nothing happens when I should get the "clicked" alert message.

Any idea ?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the entire map is rendered in an iWindow, so no javascript you write externally will affect the map just like that.

Comment: @Codemonkey, in fact I do not want to affect the map, just to be able to trigger a javascript function attached to a "a" tag in a infowindow.

Answer (score 0):

I solved a similar problem by using [this example](http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/overlayview/custommarker.html) instead of the InfoBox object.